# Is this correct to say "You are having incorrect installer"?

Tags: tense, stative-verbs

Which one is correct to say?

> "You are having incorrect installer."

or

> "You have incorrect installer."

Comment: You don't have the right installer.

Comment: Or, That's not (you don't have) the *proper* installer.

Answer (score 4):

> You have the incorrect installer.

*Have* is not an action in this sentence. It is a state or condition.

> possess, own, or hold.
> "he had a new car and a boat"
>
> [— Oxford Dictionary of English, oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/have)

When a verb describes a state or condition, we usually don't use the verb with *-ing*.

You can search for "stative verb" to find more information, or see, for example, [this discussion of stative verbs on perfect-english-grammar.com](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/stative-verbs.html).